# Set different font sizes for characters within a Tkinter label or button in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am working on a Tkinter application in Python, and I have a label/button with text "Aa." I want to set different font sizes for the characters, for example : "A" with a font size of 20 and "a" with a font size of 15.

Here's the code snippet with my attempt:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Label with Different Font Sizes")

# Create a label for the entire text
label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 20))
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

# Add labels for each character with different font sizes
label_a = tk.Label(label, text="A", font=("Helvetica", 20), anchor="w")
label_b = tk.Label(label, text="a", font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor="w")

# Place labels on the grid
label_a.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
label_b.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```

I I've tried using separate labels for each character, but it doesn't produce the desired result. Can someone provide a clear example or guidance on how to set different font sizes for individual characters within a Tkinter label or button?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don' think you can place a label inside another label. But you can use a frame to contain labels with different font size.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Frame(root, bg='wheat')  # Bg to show label size on window
label.pack(padx=100, pady=30)

# Add labels for each character with different font sizes
label_a = tk.Label(label, text="A", font=("Helvetica", 40), anchor="w")
label_b = tk.Label(label, text="a", font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor="w")

# Place labels on the grid
label_a.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
label_b.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=(22,0))  # Push down small text

root.mainloop()
```

I'm using a bigger font for `label_a` to show that the font size affects the vertical placement of the labels inside the frame. Then you will have to use `pady=(22,0)` to push the label with smaller font towards the bottom. Bg color to highligth the extension of the frame.

**Correction**
Seems I misunderstood this question. As far as I have been able to determine a `Label` can only use one font. My example above does the same thing as @Hrishikesh is providing, but with a slightly different widget use.

Comment: Yes, you can place one label inside another.

Comment: @Bryan, checked all the documentation I could find and none of it mentions this. But I'm learning new things every day :)